# How can I replace df.iterrows() with df.apply() in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the following loop:

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
for (i, row) in df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].iterrows():
            dict1[row['col1']] = row['col2']
            dict2[row['col1']] = row['col3']
```

and as far as I could see this loops is really slow (I've got about 70'000 rows in my dataframe `df`).

Is there any way to speed it up? I googled a bit and they say I should use `df.apply()` instead of `.iterrows()`.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You may not need any loops as it appears you just need to convert series to dict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
m=df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
dict1=m.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict()
dict2=m.set_index('col1')['col3'].to_dict()
```